# Google images layout with angularjs and ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to make an image gallery that is similar to Google images gallery layout but I couldn't find any useful example to approach. I would like to show the larger image right below or above the image that is clicked using `angularjs`.

I started working on a plunker example but don't have any idea how to achieve this. I could able to display the image either on the top of all images or below all the images. Any thoughts on how to achieve this using `angularjs` and `ui-bootstrap`. Thanks in advance.

> Plunker Link : https://plnkr.co/edit/IN65NEXKUDNFWIZeXDci?p=preview

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="image in images track by $index">
      <img src="{{image}}" ng-click="collapse=!collapse; setImage(image)" style="height:100px;width:100px;float:left;padding:20px;cursor:pointer">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img uib-collapse="collapse" src="{{img}}"style="height:500px;width:500px;padding:20px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there. Only thing missing was to move the image inside the repeater.

Added this to your controller.

```
$scope.setImage = function(index){
  $scope.visibleIndex = index;
}
```

And this to your markup:

```
<div ng-show="visibleIndex == $index"><br />
  <img src="{{image}}" style="height:500px;width:500px;padding:20px">
</div>
```

I have updated your plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/IN65NEXKUDNFWIZeXDci?p=preview

Comment: I've implemented your idea but it is not close to the Google images layout https://plnkr.co/edit/IN65NEXKUDNFWIZeXDci?p=preview